# Simple Wicket / Maven quickstart problem

Tags: maven-2, wicket

Wicket gives a simple "quickstart" command generator for use with Maven on their homepage at http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html

I installed this and understand that Maven automatically downloads requisites that it needs from its central repository.  But when I run the command it generates, I get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.161s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 06 22:07:28 EDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\xxxxxx\Projects\[project dir]). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the message suggests that Maven didn'recognize archetype plugin.
Can you copy and paste exact command that you are using?
Are using Windows cmd shell?
Try escaping arguments.

Comment: I was actually using PowerShell.  Apparently doing exactly the same thing in cmd.exe worked fine; PowerShell must have done something crazy with the arguments.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: and thanks for your hint! I was running into the same problem and found that if I quoted all the arguments (something you often have to do with powershell and other tools, which is why I am surprised this didn't occur to me earlier) it worked. In my case, I found specifically it was a -Dversion=1.2.3 that was causing the problem. Thanks again!